# Can we synthesis pico materials or femto materials?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, nanoscience

Currently we know that the radius of an atom is of the order $10^{-10} m$ and nucleus' radius is of the order $10^{-15}m.$ We also know that nano-materials does exist and can be synthesised by various methods. My question is : **Can pico-materials be synthesised theoretically and practically ?**

To add on my question, I am not necessarily asking about materials consisting of atoms but these materials could be of particles like neutrons. The material may be $1-D$ confined (a sheet) or other types like tubes or dots.

Now I understand that any material (made up of atoms) in between the size of the atom and nucleus will be very unstable, which is why the question: Is it possible to synthesize pico-materials involving just the particles ?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment:

> I was wondering if it is possible to synthesis these materials involving just the particles.

Elementary particles are what "synthesize" the atoms, within our mainstream standard model. To get stable composite bound states below the size of the atom is not possible.

In particular , [neutrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron) by themselves are unstable, decaying within minutes, because the proton is a lower energy bound state of elementary particles to which the neutron can decay. They cannot form a stable bound state.

Comment: Insight about neutrons was helpful, thank you. Could you clarify other part of the question that if we consider different types of confinements then what are the possibilities ?

Comment: In order to have a material, its charge should be zero, that is what atoms do. This is electromagnetic confinement . The nuclei are stable confined by the strong interaction in combination with the electromagnetic, but they are charged, so two nuclei cannot form a bound state due to the electromagnetic repulsion, You have to be satisfied with atomic distances,